# How to use $1 in ${} in shell script

Tags: shell

```sh
function print_array(){
    NUMBER=1
    for i in ${$1[@]}; do
        printf "%d: %s \n" $NUMBER $i
        $((NUMBER++))
    done
}
```

I want to write a function that can accept an array as a parameter and print all things inside the array.

So I wrote something like ${$1[@]}, and shell said that's a "bad substitution".

Any ways to achieve the same effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with this code, but the primary is one is that `$1` will never be an array. If you want to pass an array to a function, you would need to do something like this:

```
print_array(){
    NUMBER=1
    for i in "${@}"; do
        printf "%d: %s \n" $NUMBER "$i"
        ((NUMBER++))
    done
}

myarray=(this is "a test" of arrays)
print_array  "${myarray[@]}"
```

This will output:

```
1: this 
2: is 
3: a test 
4: of 
5: arrays
```

Note that the quoting in this script is critical: Writing `${myarray[@]}` is not the same as writing `"${myarray[@]}"`; see the [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) section of the bash manual for details, as well as the [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) section for information about `$@` vs `"$@"`.